# Getting Unicode character in WM_KEYDOWN

Tags: windows, keyboard, winapi

In an application where I need to handle a lot of keys differently I want to handle all cases in WM_KEYDOWN and not use WM_CHAR at all. Is it possible to obtain the correct ASCII/UNICODE character from a sequence of WM_KEYDOWN supplied Virtual Keys instead of relying on the more regular TranslateMsg / WM_CHAR?

As an example: the application should be able to handle Shift-B in a totally different manner that pressing a regular B of CTRL-B.

Using MapVirtualKey, you do not use the state of the Shift, Control and Alt keys, or at least not that I can see.

As Leo Davidson answered: you can use the ToUnicode call to perform the VK -> Unicode conversion yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) deals with character codes, which basically means physical keys on the keyboard.

If you want to deal with unicode characters, handle [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646276%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (16-bit Unicode chars, assuming your window itself is unicode) or [WM_UNICHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646288%28VS.85%29.aspx) (32-bit Unicode chars) instead.

EDIT: If you want to do the conversion yourself, use the [ToUnicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646320%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API.

Comment: This I know. I asked the question to see if the logic from TranslateMsg that sends the WM_CHAR is also obtainable using another path not using windows messages (like an API call)

Comment: This looks promising: Will try it out directly! Learning a new WinAPI call every day..